# Flutter: Don't get class type variable initialized

Tags: class, flutter, dart, initialization

Apologies for this stupid question, but obviously I don't get my search keywords right or the solution is so straight obvious to others that it hasn't been asked yet. Previously, I had no problem with the initialization and I do not understand what is different here.

I have a variable based on a data class and I want to assign values to it

```dart
class MyData {
  int id;
  String description;
  MyData({
    this.id,
    this.description,
  });

  factory MyData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
    return new ProblemTask(
      id: parsedJson['id'],
      taskText: parsedJson['decription'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'id': id,
    'taskText': description,
  };
}


class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage>{
  MyData myVar;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myVar = MyData();
  }
    
  _onDone() {
    myVar.id = 1;
    myVar.description = "abc";
  }
}
```

This results in

**The setter 'descr=' was called on null.**

**Receiver: null**

But my understanding is that I create an empty instance with `myVar = MyData();` which I expected to catch my values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few misspelled parameters:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyData {
  int id;
  String description;
  MyData({
    this.id,
    this.description,
  });

  factory MyData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
    return new MyData( // MyData instead ProblemTask
      id: parsedJson['id'],
      description: parsedJson['description'], //description instead of taskText
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'id': id,
    'taskText': description,
  };
}

class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyPageState createState() => _MyPageState();
}

class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
 MyData myVar;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
   myVar = new MyData(id:1,description:'abc');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Houssem. Sorry about the typos, I did not copy my code but typed the essence here. The classes etc are a bit more complex, hence I would like to avoid an assignment like `myVar = new MyData(id:1,description:'abc');` and do it step by step with .id = xy (with xy being a line filling expression). My understanding is that in Dart I do not have to assign all values at once

Comment: Apologies, big user error: Yesterday, I always hot reloaded the code to the simulator instead of restarting. Any changes I did to the initialization were not executed. I noticed today, when I wanted to check your value based initialization. So still, your answer was a big help :-)